# Android Retrofit 2.0: no response to HTTP call

Tags: retrofit

I am an Android developer, I am working with `Retrofit`. The first day I had a response but the second day the response did not come, why I will working after I can uninstall and install the app then only it will work why, how to I resolve it please help me...

```
private void HomeWorks() {
    HomeWorkApi homeWorkApi =
            MissReportServer.getClient().create(HomeWorkApi.class);
    Call<VrrittamResponse<ArrayList<HomeWork>>> call =
            homeWorkApi.getHomeWork(access_token);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<VrrittamResponse<ArrayList<HomeWork>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<VrrittamResponse<ArrayList<HomeWork>>> call, Response<VrrittamResponse<ArrayList<HomeWork>>> response) {
            try {
                ArrayList<HomeWork> homeWork = response.body().getContent();

                if (homeWork != null && !homeWork.isEmpty()) {

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new HomeWorkAdapter(homeWork,
                            R.layout.list_item_homework, getActivity()));
                }
                else {
                    ExceptionHandle.alertDialogNotShow(getActivity());
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex){
                ExceptionHandle.alertDialogNotShow(getActivity());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<VrrittamResponse<ArrayList<HomeWork>>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("TAG",t.getMessage());
            ExceptionHandle.alertDialogShow(getActivity());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "why I will working after I can uninstall and install the app then only it will work why, how to I resolve it please help me...  "?

Comment: i am using retrofit 2.0, my app in play store, when i am install the app that day can work after that day, i will open the app the response cannot get.why response cannot get.

Comment: You need to add more code. Are you sure the server is running and that it is accessible? Are you sure that the authentication (access_token) is correct? Do you see any error in the logs?

Comment: i have a access_token and API 's but i will come null object reference why it happened. if uninstall and install the app then only it will be working ..

Comment: Which object is null?

Comment: response will be null

Comment: You get a call to onResponse with a null response object? That should never happen. Something else is wrong but I can't tell from the code you posted. Are you sure that retrofit does not call onFailure instead?